# Inserstion a new node in a binary tree to a specific node inside the tree

Tags: node.js, binary-search-tree, addition, treenode

I need to create a function :
public static BinaryTree getFamilyTree(String path)
the String path is a location inside the computer

I`m using scanner and file reader to read those strings and adding them by split(,) like,this = {"like", "this"} to a String array and putting these string as the node data.

```
public static BinaryTree getFamilyTree(String path) {
    File fr = new File(path);
    BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
    try {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(fr);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String st = sc.nextLine();
            String [] carry = st.split(",");
            BTNode [] he = new BTNode [3];
            for (int j = 0; j < carry.length; j++) {
                he[j] = new BTNode(carry[j]);
            }
            LinkedList role = new LinkedList();
            role.AddFirst(carry[0]);
            if(bt.getRoot()==null)
                bt.setRoot(he[0]);
            if(contains(role, bt)){
                if(SearchB(bt.getRoot(), he[0].getData()) != null) {
                    if(carry.length == 3) {
                        if (bt.getRoot().getLeft() == null) 
                        {
                            bt.getRoot().setLeft(new BTNode(carry[2]));
                            bt.getRoot().getLeft().setParent(bt.getRoot());}
                        if (bt.getRoot().getRight() == null)
                        {
                            bt.getRoot().setRight(new BTNode(carry[2]));
                            bt.getRoot().getRight().setParent(bt.getRoot());}
                    }
                    else if(carry.length == 2) 
                    {
                         if(bt.getRoot().getLeft() == null) {
                            bt.getRoot().setLeft(new BTNode(carry[1]));
                            bt.getRoot().getLeft().setParent(bt.getRoot());}
                    }

                }
            }
        }} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bt;
    }
```

** file for example:** (Parent,LeftChild,RightChild)

- Papa Smurf, Hefty Smurf, Grouchy Smurf
- Grouchy Smurf, Jokey Smurf, Vanity Smurf
- Jokey Smurf, Greedy Smurf, Handy Smurf
- Hefty Smurf, Brainy Smurf, Painter Smurf
- Handy Smurf, Farmer Smurf
- Brainy Smurf, Snappy Smurfling, Slouchy Smurfling

The Names has no meaning for me except one thing the Names that are first in line those are to parent Node

I`m using scanner and file reader to read those strings and adding them by split(,) like this to a String array and putting these string as the node data.

I`m having trouble with adding the nodes to where I want . because I need to Search for the node and than adding his childerns .

```
public static BTNode SearchB(BTNode root, String data) 
{ 
    if (null == root || null == data) return root;
    String rootStr = root.getData();
    if (rootStr.compareToIgnoreCase(data) == 0) return root;
    BTNode left = SearchB(root.getLeft(), data);
    if(null != left) return left;
    BTNode right = SearchB(root.getRight(), data);
    if (null != right) return right;
    return null;
}
```

Im using this code for searching inside the BinaryTree for a specific data inside the Tree - The data that I`m looking for is the parent name so I can add his childerns according to the file

thank you very much sorry for the long question :)

Comment: What's `root `? If you want to define a variable you must use `var`, `let`, or `const`, for example: `const rootStr = root.getData();`. If you want to declare a variable with a type you need [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), and then you can do `const rootStr: string = root.getData();`. But anyway, I think you should try to rewrite your question, that's not understandable. Give us more of your logic and more of your code.

Comment: I edit above thanks for the heads up
I did my best to explain all that Im trying to do